# How to view decompiled R code in order to debug it?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, decompiling

I'm working with `ASSIGN SESSION:DEBUG-ALERT = TRUE.` and as a result, while testing a program I get an error message with following callstack details (only the first line):

```
--> USER-INTERFACE-TRIGGER my_own_window.w at line 587  (\\<official_build_server_directory>\my_own_window.r)
    my_own_window.w at line 709  (\\<official_build_server>\<my_own_window.r)
    ...
```

As you can see, something's wrong with my window at lines 587 and 709, but:
While compiling the window files, some things happen which mess with the line numbers, and the mentioned line numbers are the ones from the compiled *.r files, which are different than the ones from the original *.w files.
In order to be sure about the line numbers, I would need a de-compiler, or at least a *.r-viewer (being based on an internal de-compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the r-code's you need to look into. It's the DEBUG-LISTING files. If you have the source-code execute:

```
COMPILE my_own_window.w DEBUG-LIST c:\temp\my-own_window.debuglist .
```

That file shows you the actual line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: so far Progress has not provided a decompiler. Any available decompilers at the time of writing this are 3rd party and also possibly not legal regarding Progress OpenEdge licenses.

Answer (score 2):

You can also click on the 'Debug' button in that alert box, which will invoke the debugger which steps through an 'on the fly' debug-listing.

For the debug-listing on the fly to work, you will need to have the source files in your `propath`. The debugger will detect and complain if source files have changed after your code was executed.

And you will also need to ensure the debugger is enabled by starting [proenv](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/gsins/using-the-proenv-utility.html) and then [prodebugenable -enable-all](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pdsoe/enabling-debugging.html.)